# JavaScript check for the first zero in 2 digits

Tags: javascript

I have a text field with 2 digits in it as user input.
I want to take out the first digit if its 0.

Example

> 01
> 02
> 03

will become:

> 1
> 2
> 3

whereas:

> 11
> 12
> 13

will not change.

How to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
var a="07";
alert(a-0);
```

Comment: Great idea, converting a string with leading zeros to an **octal** number.

Comment: No octal numbers involved here.

Comment: @Ivo, Erik is right, *no octal conversion is made* with this method, that's a problem of the built-in `parseInt` function (already fixed on ES5, and hopefully *some day* will be implemented...). I would also mention two other ways, using the *unary plus operator*: `alert(+a);` (short and sweet :) or the `Number` constructor called as a function: `alert(Number(a));` which are at the end equivalent to a "no-op" arithmetic operation as `a-0` or `a*1`... More info about String to Number conversion and octals: [Why doesn't an octal literal as a string cast to a number?](http://j.mp/gBwiBx). Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, CMS, for the long answer - I didn't have time. I am a little surprised that my "hack" has been voted up. Surely it can't be the best solution.

Comment: @CMS Dang, getting to paranoid about JS these days, you're right on that one, I'll remove my down vote and stand corrected (Note to my self: Next time go a bit earlier to bed...)

Comment: Agree, it's hacky but does the job. You don't wanna write code like this professionally.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple

```
var str = "07";  
str = Number(str);  
alert(str); // will return 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if str.substring(0) = "0" && str.length == 2
   str = str.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use .replace()

for example...

```
    if(string1.substring(0) =="0"){
    string1.substring(0).replace("0","");
      }
```

then parseInt back back to int

```
int int1 = string1.parseInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you realy have 2 digits:

```
var str = "09";
str = str[0] === '0' ? str[1] : str;
```

Or you can take a more general approach

```
String.prototype.trimLeadingZeros = function () {
  var x = this || '', i;
  for(i = 0;i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i] !== '0') {
      return x.substring(i);
    }
  }
};

​window.alert("000000102305"​.trimLeadingZeros());​
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Javascript is interpreting the values as string. You can use 2 ways to convert.
Assuming you save the digit into a variable called myNumber:
var myNumber = "01";

1st way is to type the assignment

```
myNumber = Number(myNumber);
```

2nd way is to use the *parseInt* function

```
myNumber = parseInt(myNumber);
```

If later, you want the variable in String again

```
myNumber = String(myNumber);
```

Or better yet, you can do everything on one line.

```
var myNumber = String(Number(myNumber))
```

and

```
var myNumber = String(parseInt(myNumber))
```